# Do I have to use "xxforms:evaluate" in action-loops to use iterator?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I had a problem with updating instance structure which contains repeating nodes. I wanted to use `&lt;action while=""/&gt;` construction but there was a problem using defined iterator inside this loop. Eventually it always used one value (first one) even though it was incremented. I resolved this problem by using `xxforms:evaluate` function thus I have:

```
xxforms:evaluate(concat('instance(''main'')/item[',xxforms:bind('idx'),']'))
```

instead of simpler

```
instance('main')/item[xxforms:bind('idx')]
```

Is this the only way to iterate across the list of nodes inside an action?

Example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <xf:model id="model">
      <xf:instance id="main" xmlns="">
        <main>
          <item>
            <name />
          </item>
          <item>
            <name />
          </item>
          <item>
            <name />
          </item>
        </main>
      </xf:instance>
      <xf:instance id="temp" xmlns="">
        <main>
          <idx></idx>
          <value>inserted node</value>
        </main>
      </xf:instance>

      <xf:bind id="idx" nodeset="instance('temp')/idx" type="xsd:integer" />
    </xf:model>
  </head>

   <body>
    <xf:trigger>
      <xf:label>Not working as expected</xf:label>
      <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value="1" />
        <xf:action while="number(xxforms:bind('idx')) le count(instance('main')/item)">
          <xf:insert context="instance('main')/item[xxforms:bind('idx')]" nodeset="name" position="after" origin="instance('temp')/value" if="not(exists(value))" />
          <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value=". + 1" />
        </xf:action>
      </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>

    <xf:trigger>
      <xf:label>Working as expected but too complicated</xf:label>
      <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value="1" />
        <xf:action while="number(xxforms:bind('idx')) le count(instance('main')/item)">
          <xf:insert context="xxforms:evaluate(concat('instance(''main'')/item[',xxforms:bind('idx'),']'))" nodeset="name" position="after" origin="instance('temp')/value" if="not(exists(value))" />
          <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value=". + 1" />
        </xf:action>
      </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>
    <widget:xforms-instance-inspector id="orbeon-xforms-inspector" xmlns:widget="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/widget" />
   </body>
</html>
```

So I get as a result (first trigger):

```
<main>
  <item>
    <name/>
    <value>inserted node</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name/>
  </item>
</main>
```

but expected (second trigger):

```
<main>
  <item>
    <name/>
    <value>inserted node</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name/>
    <value>inserted node</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name/>
    <value>inserted node</value>
  </item>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that works:

```
<xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
    <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value="1"/>
    <xf:action while="xs:integer(xxforms:bind('idx')) le count(instance('main')/item)">
        <xf:insert context="instance('main')/item[xs:integer(xxforms:bind('idx'))]" nodeset="name" position="after"
                   origin="instance('temp')/value" if="not(exists(value))"/>
        <xf:setvalue bind="idx" value=". + 1"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:action>
```

The issue is that `xxforms:bind('idx')` returns an untyped value, even through you specified `xsd:integer`. XForms currently doesn't specify that type annotations on binds must cause a typed value to be provided (see these [notes on type annotation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xpath-2-0-support#TOC-Type-annotations)). This means that in this case, the predicate value is not a number (XPath has both boolean and numeric predicates, and this is often a source of confusion). In order to make it a numeric predicate, converting to a number is needed.

Here I use `xs:integer` as `number` is kind of an XPath 1 legacy function, and it returns an `xs:double` while the `count()` function returns an `xs:integer`).

There is much simpler solution with `xxforms:iterate`:

```
<xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" xxforms:iterate="item">
    <xf:insert if="not(exists(value))"
               context="."
               nodeset="name"
               origin="instance('temp')/value"/>
</xf:action>
```

`iterate` is currently an extension, but [XForms 2 will add it.](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/@iterate)